# Maya Kodnani's phonecalls to Narendra Modi during a massacre

Tags: india

During the [Naroda-Patiya massacre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naroda_Patiya_massacre), Maya Kodnani (who was the sitting BJP MLA from the same area during the time of conviction) was found to be on the site during the violence in 2002, contrary to her claims. This was settled by the use of telephone records as reported in [this article](https://www.hindustantimes.com/delhi-news/naroda-verdict-may-spell-trouble-for-top-cops-ex-minister/story-GIKzSXvLpKQkrUovTOE9DM.html).

As I read in this article, the phone records show that while the massacre in which she participated was ongoing, Maya Kodnani was also in touch with the [Gordhan Zadafia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gordhan_Zadafia), the then Home minister of Gujarat and Narendra Modi, the Chief-minister then and the current prime minister of India.

The complicity of the Gujarat government during the 2002 riots is a hotly debated matter and has very important political implications. While a Special Investigation Team that found that Narendra Modi was not complicit in the riots, this particular piece of information seems to be in conflict with the findings.

Is this news story reliable? And if it is true, are there any responses known by the BJP or Narendra Modi about this exact piece of information via any interview or otherwise?

Comment: I feel obliged to note that this article is nearly seven years old.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what the question here is.  Is there any reason to _doubt_ that she was in touch with Gordhan?  And why would it matter if she was?

Comment: She was acquitted eventually, https://www.bbc.com/news/world-asia-india-43834715 So I'm not sure how her phone contacts matter much anymore.

Comment: I don't understand why this question is on hold! I have made what I am asking very clear and it is very relevant to Indian politics.

Comment: I don't understand why the question is closed. The OP is very clear about what is the question.

Comment: @NiteeshShanbog - You're right.  The question itself is clear, even if I don't understand why someone would ask it.  Just because Kodnani called Modi doesn't mean Modi knew anything about what she was in the middle of, which is what the Special Investigation Team seems to have found.  I've voted to reopen, but I encourage the OP to explain why they think this is a question in the first place.

Comment: @Bobson I guess that is because she had claimed not to be in town when the riots happened but then her call records proved otherwise.